# disable enum assignment g++ in if statement

Tags: c++, g++

I would like to treat assignment in an if statement as error:

```
#include <cstdio>

enum some {
    a,
    b
};

void foo(some e) {
    if (e = a) {
        puts("yes");
    } else {
        puts("no");
    }
}

int main() {
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

This seems like a sane thing to do, except that I'd like to have something like this too:

```
boost::optional<int> optionalValue;
if (const auto& value = optionalValue) {

}
```

`-Wall` gives me `enum.cpp:9: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`, but I would like to have something more specific than `-Wall`

Comment: @YuriyOrlov You missed the point. Read the question again.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov yes, I know. I would like to make g++ blame if it encounters this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `e` to be `const`. Then assignment would be an error.

Or, you can tell g++ to treat warnings as errors with `-Werror`. Then, coupled with the appropriate warning setting, any assignment in a `if` expression will be an error. You can enable only this class of warnings with `-Wparentheses` However, do note that sometimes it's not a mistake, but done on purpose. Which is why g++ suggests using parentheses to disambiguate from accidental assignment.

Comment: Is it possible to make that particular enum not convertible to an integer type?

Comment: You could use a scoped enum instead of an unscoped enum. Scoped enums are not implicitly convertible to integers.

Comment: @user2079303: or `enum class` since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a more recent version of g++ then it tells you which warning flag corresponds to which diagnostic. Using g++ 4.9.2 your code gives :

```
m.cc:9:14: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

This tells you that the error comes from the flag `-Wparentheses`, which is a subset of `-Wall`.

You can instruct g++ to treat all warnings as errors by using `-Werror`.  But if you only want to treat this particular warning as an error then you can use:

```
-Werror=parentheses
```

This version of g++ does not warn for your suggested code `const auto& value = optionalValue`, so perhaps it's time to upgrade your compiler version.